# Problem with blue-sceens

Tags: windows, bsod

I have a problem with my computer. I get bluescreens a lot. I get different bluescreen-codes everytime, and this happens randomly. This can happen when I boot my computer, when I'm surfing on the internett, when I'm away from the computer and are logged out...

I tried to disconnect everything that was connected to my computer, beside the monitor. That didn't help. I have reinstalled Windows, changed memory, changed video card, but nothing of this helped, I still get bluescreens.

I guess the problem here is the mothercard, CPU or HDD. But I want your opinion before I order anything new to my computer. Can you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Did you reformat the drive when you reinstalled your operating system? Have you scanned it for bad sectors? Maybe if you had another HDD lying around, you could pop it in and see if the box still BSODs.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be caused by:

1. 'Dirty' mains (try your PC in another building or buy a mains filter)
2. PSU failing (borrow a replacement)
3. Failing/failed fan or dust clogged filter/air intake (easy to see)
4. Intermittent connection (remake all connections, power and data)

Comment: Thanks. 1. and 3. Done. What do you meen by number four? Just remove every connections to my computer and connect it again?

Comment: Is it, by the way, possible that it could be the mothercard, CPU, or HDD too?

Comment: Yes, remove the internal connectors one at a time and refit them. The mainboard, CPU & HDD are all options to look at, but I would try the easy and cheap stuff first.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I have already tried 1, 3, and 4, and I'm not able to borrow a PSU. So I propoply need to guess what to buy. CPU, mainboard, HDD, or PSU. What would you buy first? ;)

Comment: Personally, I'd take it to a repair shop. Any advice I gave at this stage could be wrong and costly.

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned the network card at all. Is it on-board or PCI? I'd have a look at putting in a new NIC to see if that alleviates the problem, especially if you've checked almost everything else.

Comment: It's on-board. I have checked everything that can be checked now, and have ordered new mainboard. Hopes this will help :)

Comment: motherboard i ment

Comment: I would have tried the network card first, but a new motherboard should fix the problem.